# Number format. I want an input two decimal places on ng-blur without directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

number format. i want an input two decimal places on ng-blur without directive

i tried with directive which is working fine.

```
define(['angular', 'mainModule'], function(angular, mainModule) {
    'use strict';
    mainModule.directive('numbformat', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
                if (!controller) return;
                var DECIMAL_COUNT = 2;

                if(attrs.decimal){//if require to change decimal value specify declimal value as attribute in HTML
                    DECIMAL_COUNT = attrs.decimal;
                }

                controller.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                    return $filter(attrs.numbformat)(controller.$modelValue, DECIMAL_COUNT);
                });

                //For on Blur of Element manage Decimal and Format issuse
                elem.on('blur' , function() {

                    elem.val($filter(attrs.numbformat)(controller.$modelValue, DECIMAL_COUNT));
                });

                //For on Focus of Element manage Decimal and Format issuse
                elem.on('focus' , function(){
                    var actVal = $filter(attrs.numbformat)(controller.$modelValue)
                    elem.val(actVal);
                    elem[0].select();
                });

                controller.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                    var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                    var actVal = plainNumber.toString();

                    if(actVal.indexOf('.') > -1 || actVal.indexOf('-') > -1){
                        return plainNumber;
                    }else{
                        elem.val($filter(attrs.numbformat)(plainNumber));
                    }

                    return plainNumber;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
})
```

but it is giving me performance issues on IE11.
because directive is called on every input which is wrong so m trying it without directive and converting to it

```
ng-keyup="formatval($event,'ExpStatement.MinVal')"
ng-blur="formatValBlur($event,'ExpStatement.MinVal')"
```

now ng-keyup will allow only decimals or number
and on blur i want to decimal compulsory

in short i want to converting the directive. or any one help me to convert or any feasible solution to this

i tried this one but not working

```
   $scope.formatval = function(event , val){
     $scope.val = $filter('number')( parseFloat($scope.val.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, "")) );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only allow a number in the textbox with (see here for more info including showing error if not a number https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

```
<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="number only" required>
```

In your angular blur event/keyup function, use regular javascript to format the number.

```
$scope.val.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help you : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gsferreira/Lsv9f0b0/

It use native api :

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" required />
```